# Cambio de variable pero me da error al momento de hacerlo y no muestra nada de lo que hay en la base de datos

Tags: html, python, css, bootstrap, django

**Quiero añadirle estilos a los atributos fk_rol, fk_unidad y fk_contrato, que sean de tipo selección, pero al momento de cambiarle el TextImput queda como texto y no me deja seleccionar las distintas opciones que hay en la base de datos, tambien cuando cambio su variable a select, no me muestra nada, help please**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Usuario

class CrearUser(forms.ModelForm):

    nombre_full = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    rut = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    fec_nac = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    genero = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block"}))
    fk_rol = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block form-select"}))
    fk_unidad = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block form-select"}))
    fk_contrato = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control d-block form-select"}))
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = '__all__'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu modelo si tienes esos campos como llaves foráneas? Podrías agregarlo?

Comment: Hola, si esos campos son llaves foráneas en mi modelo Usuario, gracias por responder ♡

Answer (score 0):

```
class Meta:
    model = Usuario
    fields = [
        'nombre_full',
        'rut',
        'username',
        'password',
        'fec_nac',
        'genero',
        'fk_rol',
        'fk_unidad',
        'fk_contrato'
    ]
    labels ={
        'nombre_full':'Nombre Completo',
        'rut':'RUT',
        'username':'Usuario',
        'password':'Contraseña',
        'fec_nac':'Fecha de Nacimiento',
        'genero':'Genero',
        'fk_rol':'Rol',
        'fk_unidad':'Unidad Interna',
        'fk_contrato':'Contrato',
    }
    widgets = {
        'nombre_full': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'rut': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'password': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'fec_nac': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'genero': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block'}),
        'fk_rol': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block form-select'}),
        'fk_unidad': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block form-select'}),
        'fk_contrato': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control d-block form-select'}),
    }
```

**Al final solo tuve que cambiar la estructura que estaba usando, mmh se podría decir que tuve que separar los atributos de los widgets y asimismo agregar una clase de labels para el nombre de los campos, adjunto resultado deseado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]